# SyntaxError: invalid syntax // SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

How do I detect text inside of this, this is HTML & this is XPath. I tried

```
HTML
    <span class="messageText">Hello.</span>
XPath
    //*[@id="liveAgentChatLogText"]/span[22]/span[2]
```

I tried with this but it didn't work, it said no such element found.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="liveAgentChatLogText"]//*[contains(string(.), "Hello")]')
```

Comment: Please don't post multiple near-identical questions - instead edit your first question to add the information you need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can refer any of the xpath which is given below, to locate the element using text :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Hello.']")
```

Here you have to pass the complete sting which your element has else it wont work.

**OR**

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(.,'Hello.')]")
```

You can use `contains` method in xpath to get your element matching based on full or partial given text.

**OR**

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='messageText'][contains(.,'Hello.')]")   //recommended
```

To make more robust you can include attribute of that particular tag. here i have used `class` attribute of span, that means span which have `class=messageText` and contain `text=Hello`.

Still you are facing issue in getting element, try `ExplicitWaits` until they are loaded in DOM.

Answer (score 0):

As per the given HTML you can use below mentioned xpath that we usually use in [automation testing company](https://www.qasource.com/automation-testing-services/#!automation-testing-company).

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Hello.']")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='messageText'][text()='Hello.']")
```

You can use contains method in xpath as well to get the element text partially. Also to make it more specific (or robust) can include attribute of that particular tag

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Hello.')]")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='messageText'][contains(text(),'Hello.')]")
```

Hope above solution will help and if you still face issue in getting the element try to wait for visibility of element or please provide more line of code (HTML)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` error occurs when there is a problem with the syntax of your code. In this case, it is possible that there is a syntax error in the code that comes before the line of code you provided.

Regarding your question, to detect text inside the HTML element and XPath you mentioned, you can use the `text` property of the `WebElement` class in Selenium. Here is an example code snippet that should work:

```
# Find the element using XPath
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="liveAgentChatLogText"]/span[22]/span[2]')

# Get the text of the element
text = element.text

# Print the text
print(text)
```

This code will find the element using the XPath you provided, and then retrieve the text inside the element using the `text` property. Finally, it will print the text to the console.

If the `NoSuchElementException` is still being thrown with this code, it could mean that the element is not present on the page or not loaded yet. In this case, you can try to add a wait before finding the element to ensure it is loaded:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Wait for the element to be visible
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="liveAgentChatLogText"]/span[22]/span[2]')))

# Get the text of the element
text = element.text

# Print the text
print(text)
```

This code adds a 10-second wait for the element to be visible before trying to retrieve its text. If the element is still not present after 10 seconds, a `TimeoutException` will be thrown.